# copy column value of one file(CSV) to another XML formatted file

Tags: xml, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have millions of data and I'm trying to insert column value from one file1 to another file2. Where File1 is CSV file ("|"pipe seperated) has data as below

```
1.1.1.1|LM
1.2.3.4|MV
10.113.45.123|MN
```

and File2 is XML format based file:

```
<xml version="01">
        <raw_data>
                <Add>
                        <value IP="" META=""></value>
                        <value IP="" META=""></value>
                        <value IP="" META=""></value>
                </Add>
        </raw_data>
</xml>
```

Here i want to copy column 1st of FILE1 to FILE2(IP) and column 2nd to META of FILE2 as below:

```
    <xml version="01">
        <raw_data>
                <Add>
                        <value IP="1.1.1.1" META="LM"></value>
                        <value IP="1.2.3.4" META="MV"></value>
                        <value IP="10.113.45.123" META="MN"></value>
                </Add>
        </raw_data>
   </xml>
```

So finally the output should looks like as above.

Comment: What's the content of the Xml file prior to modifying it, and did you consider rewriting the whole Xml instead of in-place editing?

Comment: [My edit comment](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47493633/2) referred to a rejected edit request.

Answer (score 2):

To update multiple attributes with `bash` and `xmlstarlet`:

```
declare -i c=1                        #  set integer attribute
while IFS="|" read -r ip meta; do
  xmlstarlet edit -L --omit-decl \
    --update "//raw_data/Add/value[$c]/@IP" --value "$ip" \
    --update "//raw_data/Add/value[$c]/@META" --value "$meta" file2.xml
  c=c+1
done < file1
```

Output to file2.xml:

```
<xml version="01">
  <raw_data>
    <Add>
      <value IP="1.1.1.1" META="LM"/>
      <value IP="1.2.3.4" META="MV"/>
      <value IP="10.113.45.123" META="MN"/>
    </Add>
  </raw_data>
</xml>
```

---

**Update** to perform all changes in variable `$file`:

```
declare -i c=1                        #  set integer attribute
file=$(cat file2.xml)
while IFS="|" read -r ip meta; do
  file_mod=$(
    xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
      --update "//raw_data/Add/value[$c]/@IP" --value "$ip" \
      --update "//raw_data/Add/value[$c]/@META" --value "$meta" <<< "$file"
  )
  file="$file_mod"
  c=c+1
done < file1
echo "$file"
```

Output to stdout:

```
<xml version="01">
  <raw_data>
    <Add>
      <value IP="1.1.1.1" META="LM"/>
      <value IP="1.2.3.4" META="MV"/>
      <value IP="10.113.45.123" META="MN"/>
    </Add>
  </raw_data>
</xml>
```

---

See: `xmlstarlet edit --help`

Comment: `xmlstarlet` - the right tool for the job and that made it look so easy :)

Comment: A small disadvantage is that file2.xml is rewritten for each line in file1.

Comment: Hmm. I see and considering that the op is dealing with millions of lines would lead to some serious disk usage..

Comment: I have updated my answer to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the answer posted by Cyrus, it is good to use standard tools when it comes to reading/writing json and xml.

However if you still want to use generic linux commands, you can achieve the same using `awk` like this:

```
$ cat file 
1.1.1.1|LM
1.2.3.4|MV
10.113.45.123|MN
$ awk -F\| 'BEGIN{printf "<xml version=\"01\">\n<raw_data>\n<Add>\n"} {printf "<value IP=\"%s\" META=\"%s\"></value>\n", $1, $2} END {printf "</Add>\n</raw_data>\n</xml>\n"}' file
<xml version="01">
<raw_data>
<Add>
<value IP="1.1.1.1" META="LM"></value>
<value IP="1.2.3.4" META="MV"></value>
<value IP="10.113.45.123" META="MN"></value>
</Add>
</raw_data>
</xml>
$
```

Answer (score 0):

If `xmlstartlet` is taking long to do the job, you could try consider using `perl` but I doubt it would really do any better.

```
# cat list
1.1.1.1|LM
1.2.3.4|MV
10.113.45.123|MN
# perl -ane 's/^([^|]+)\|([^\s]+)/<value IP="\1" META="\2"><\/value>/;\
  s/^/<xml version="01">\n<raw_data>\n<Add>\n/ if $. == 1;\
  s/$/\n<\/Add>\n<\/raw_data>\n<\/xml>/ if eof;\
  print' list
<xml version="01">
<raw_data>
<Add>
<value IP="1.1.1.1" META="LM"></value>
<value IP="1.2.3.4" META="MV"></value>
<value IP="10.113.45.123" META="MN"></value>
</Add>
</raw_data>
</xml>
```

---

<sup>**Note:** Not the tidiest `perl` you could get but still. Confirm to the recommended practices like not hardcoding newlines. But I am a bit lazy for that at the moment. You could also consider using [[ **Tidy** ]](http://search.cpan.org/~pip/XML-Tidy-1.20/lib/XML/Tidy.pm)</sup>

Comment: you could use BEGIN/END and fields like the awk answer posted, no need for regex here :)

Answer (score 0):

Extended **`awk`** + **`xmlstarlet`** cooperation:

```
awk -F'|' -v cmd='xmlstarlet ed -L -u "//Add/value[%d]/@IP" -v "%s" -u "//Add/value[%d]/@META" -v "%s" file2.xml' \
'system(sprintf(cmd, NR, $1, NR, $2))' file1.csv
```

The final `file2.xml` contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml version="01">
  <raw_data>
    <Add>
      <value IP="1.1.1.1" META="LM"/>
      <value IP="1.2.3.4" META="MV"/>
      <value IP="10.113.45.123" META="MN"/>
    </Add>
  </raw_data>
</xml>
```